# Is there a way to select one whole column in a table to style differently?

Tags: html, css, xhtml

Is there a way to select one whole column in a table to style differently? without adding class or id to all those td?

I want to do with HTML and css 2.1 only. with cross browser compatibility

Comment: I liked both solution of Pavel and ruben. one is html solution and one isjquery solution. now which answer should i choose ?

Answer (score 4):

You could try to use [`<col>`](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_col.asp) element.

Comment: Yup, although I think the only CSS properties you can set for table cells using the `<col>` element are `border`, `background`, `width` and `visibility`. And I don’t know how well they’re supported.

Comment: In that link they talks about browser support

Comment: I think <col> is not supported by Firefox.

Answer (score 2):

You can select a column in a table by using [jQuery cell selector plugin](http://www.bramstein.com/projects/column/). Here is the example:

```
$('#mytable tbody td:nth-col(4)');
```

This code shows how to select the fourth column of a table.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

I think recent versions of Safari, Opera and Firefox support [the `:nth-child` CSS selector](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-nthchild#compatibilitysection), so that’s another option.

I don’t think IE 6 and 7 will give you any joy though, you’re stuck with adding classes to the `<td>`s there.